# Symfony voter - POST opreration sends null object

Tags: symfony, phpunit, api-platform.com

I'm working with `Symfony5`, `ApiPlatform` and `phpunit`

Here is my entity `POST` rule with annotation :

```
 *        "post"={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "validation_groups"={"create"},
 *              "security"="is_granted('POST', object)",
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"entityname:write"}},
 *        }
```

I'm running a test on a `POST` operation:

```
$body = '{
  "debut": "2020-11-17T14:03:10.208Z",
  "fin": "2020-11-17T14:03:10.208Z"
}';

$res = $this->buildPostPutRequest(
  Actions::POST,
  GenericRoutes::ROUTE_NAME,
  $body,
  GenericCredentials::USER_CREDENTIALS
);

$this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(403);
```

And here is my `voter`:

```
protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
{
    return parent::supports($attribute, $subject)
        && ($subject instanceof \App\Entity\EntityType || 
        $this->arrayOf($subject, \App\Entity\EntityType::class));
}

protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
{
  // Some code
}
```

Now I do receive a `403` but for the wrong reasons.

The test do not even enter the `voteOnAttribute` function, because the `supports` function return false.

If I dump the `$attribute` and `$subjet` var I receive in `supports`, I get :

```
'POST'
null
```

when I should receive:

```
'POST'
EntityType
```

Does anyone have any idea on why I receive null instead of the entity type ?

Comment: Did you checked `security.yml`? Maybe the url is restricted by firewall?

Comment: It is a bit irritating to answer to someone who does not send feedback to his [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804334/symfony-notblank-constraint-allow-blank-string).

Comment: I've found nothing in the `security.yml` that would restrict this url
Actually for this particular issue I've found a workaround with annotation that do the trick for me.
With no solution to this particular issue however.

Comment: @rugolinifr sorry for the delay, I've answered your comment which have been of great help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving `null` because of the [lifecycle](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#hooking-custom-permission-checks-using-voters), replace `security` annotation property by `security_post_denormalize`.